# Cordova Android app won't resume if Activity was killed

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity

I'm trying to make an Cordova based Android app and I'm trying to make sure the Camera Plugin works when low memory. I'm using Cordova 3.6.4.

So I tested on Android 4.4 Emulator with "Don't keep activities" checked.

Here is part of my `app.js` code:

```
(function () {
    console.log('app');

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log('deviceready');
        document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
        document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
        angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['sosApp']);
    }

    function onPause() {
        console.log('pause');
    }

    function onResume() {
        console.log('resume');
        angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['sosApp']);
    }
}());
```

When I start the app, `onDeviceReady` is called, everything works fine.

But after I launch the Camera Plugin, neither `onDeviceReady` nor `onResume` is called, therefor the `AngularJS` part was never bootstrapped.

Another problem is after taken photo, the `CameraLauncher.onActivityResult` method is never called. After debug I found that in `CordovaActivity.onActivityResult`, there is

```
this.activityResultCallback = appView.pluginManager.getPlugin(initCallbackClass);
```

which always return `null`.

I could not find any existing solution, appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: When you launch the camera plugin `onPause` should be called. Is this the case? `onResume` will be called when returning to your app. If your app has been closed and restarted `onDeviceReady` will be logged.

Comment: @Mario, Yes `onPause` was logged, but neither `onResume` nor `onDeviceReady` was logged in my case

Comment: Why are testing with the `Don't keep activities` option enabled? It will be disabled an all Android phones, except your testing device. What happens if you don't set the option? Does the app resume?

Comment: I'm testing the Camera Plugin of Cordova. According to the [doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/doc/index.md), `Android uses intents to launch the camera activity on the device to capture images, and on phones with low memory, the Cordova activity may be killed. In this scenario, the image may not appear when the Cordova activity is restored.` I'm trying to fix this issue because I need Camera to work with low memory.

Comment: If you manage to start your app after taking a picture, after is has been stopped, how do you plan to get the image data? The camera plugin has no remaining link to send any data. Sorry, I can't help. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your this is in a .java file called by Cordova, try to change it to cordova.getActivity().

Comment: Excuse me, change what to `cordova.getActivity()`?

Comment: You didn't provide any information of your `this` code. It is in a .Java file, it's referencing what? Because sometimes, some mistakes can happen. Example:

`UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);`

Instead of using `cordova.getActivity()`, people use `this` and get errors in their code. If it's not your case, then I'm sorry.

Comment: That comes from the official Cordova Android source code